# npm install - getting error in spawn sass.bat ENOENT

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, npm-install

- npm -v = 6.14.7
- Node -v = 14.7.0
- ide = VS Code
- OS = Windows 10

I'm in need of help, i'm new to building React websites - when i run a script from my package.json file (npm run pack) - kicks off the script: npm install --no-optional && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.config.js

after a while of it acting like it builds i get this error

the app.{hash#}.js file is compiled but my app wont run

i get this error

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/ruby-sass-loader!./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./src/scss/app.scss
Module build failed: Error: spawn sass.bat ENOENT
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
@ ./src/scss/app.scss 4:14-201
@ ./src/app.tsx
@ multi babel-polyfill ./src/app.tsx
Child html-webpack-plugin for "..\index.html":
      [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
      [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./framework/index.html 4.9 kB {0} [built]
      [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
      [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
Child html-webpack-plugin for "C:\Views\Home\Index.cshtml":
      [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
      [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./framework/index.html 4.9 kB {0} [built]
      [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
      [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! project@0.0.0 pack: npm install --no-optional && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.config.js
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.0 pack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ER
```

Thanks!

Comment: am i missing a global package? Are permissions in a directory wrong?

Comment: Looks like node-sass problem. Try installing it seperatly: `npm install node-sass`

Comment: Try to delete node_modules folder and re-run `npm install`

Comment: thank you guys - i tried both suggestions and no luck - i get same error as above

Comment: I've tried running ```npm install ruby``` and ```npm install ruby-sass``` and still did't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved: I was able to download and install https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ the Ruby Dev Kit for Windows then run the command `gem install sass` this resolved my build issue in Visual Studio Code - Thanks everyone for offering assistance to this weird setup issue!